# Distributive Law for Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

For what vector spaces $V$ does the distributive law of subspaces hold? $S\cap(U+T)=(S\cap U)+(S\cap T)$ for all subspaces $S,T,U$ of $V.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only holds in the trivial cases $\dim V \le 1$.

If $\dim V \ge 2$, take $S$, $T$, $U$ to be three different lines such that $S \subset U+T$, that is, $S$ lies in the subspace generated by $U$ and $T$.

Then $S\cap(U+T)=S$ but $(S\cap U)+(S\cap T)=0+0=0$.

Comment: Always exist $S\subset U+T$ such that $S\cap U= S\cap T = 0$ ?

Comment: Sure, if $U$ is generated by $u$ and $T$ by $t$, take $S$ generated by $u+t$.

Comment: Great,  Thanks !